# Drag Buttons and Drop them in a specific area in the canvas to trigger other function like page change and printing text

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, kinect-sdk, gestures

I am new with kinect V2, windows 10. I have couple of wpf buttons at the bottom on a wpf page and i want to drag each button one by one to the central area of the canvas and drop it. This should trigger the event for that button and it should navigate to a new page. How do i implement that. I have already written a code to perform simple drag and drop of those buttons. I want to know how to specify  the central area (Which would look like a rectangle )in my C# code where i could drop these buttons, which would trigger the respective button event.

I have a function private void OnManipulationCompleted in my DragDropElementController.cs .How do I specify in this different page navigation for 3 different buttons to be dragged and dropped in a different xaml page

Help me with this!

Comment: Do you have any pictures or code that could help clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I think you are a student working on project from university.. break down your tasks and ask each problem separately if you don't find the answer on the internet. And also provide pictures and code to elaborate